# Adding numbers to a cells formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Let's say `A1= X+Y`
Now I'd like to add `+Z` with a script so I end up with `A1= x+y+z`. I know how to copy it, or overwrite it, but not sure exactly how I would add to it with a changing formula in `A1`.

Some combination of `getrange` and `copyto` but also adding something to the end?

Comment: this seemed to work                                                                  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");  
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("Name");  
  var gg = first.getRange('A1');  
  first.activate();  
  gg.setFormula(first.getRange('A1').getFormula() + "+Z");`

Comment: You should post the your solution as an answer. Ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score -1):

You could also resolve this by storing variable **`z`** into the script and then call for it like:

```
var variables = [2.54]
function zzz() {
  return variables[0];
}
```

**A1:** 

```
=5+10+zzz()
```

or **A1:** 

```
=B1+C1+zzz()
```

---

**Different Example:**

[image: 0]